# How to create a nested nested array but with same name in php codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I really hope to store an array to controller in codeigniter just like this:

```
[length] => array( 
    [0] => array( 
        [0] => 3 
        [1] => 2
    )
    [1] => array( 
        [0] => 3 
        [1] => 1 
    )
);
```

This is the example of my view:

```
<div class="section">
  <input id="length" type="text" placeholder="cm" name="length[]"/>
  <input id="length" type="text" placeholder="cm" name="length[]"/>
  <a href="#!" class="btn">add field</a>
 </div>
 <div class="section">
  <input id="length" type="text" placeholder="cm" name="length[]"/>
  <input id="length" type="text" placeholder="cm" name="length[]"/>
  <a href="#!" class="btn">add field</a>
 </div>
 <a href="#!" class="btn">add design</a>
```

This is the example of my controller:

```
//hopefull this should be array just like above
$length = $this->input->post('length');
```

The name of each field is same, I have a dynamic content and also contain some dynamic input field.. When click a submit button, it will create an array based on this situation and store to some variable in controller.. if I am wrong please correct me..

This is the example of my view screenshoot:

[example screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPxst.png)

Please somebody help solve my problem, I try to figure out how to fulfill it.. Thank you so much..

It my first time to ask here in stack overflow...

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Still unclear question? Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to specify the index in the name

```
<div class="section">
 <input id="length" type="text" placeholder="cm" name="length[0][]"/>
 <input id="length" type="text" placeholder="cm" name="length[0][]"/>
 <a href="#!" class="btn">add field</a>
</div>
<div class="section">
 <input id="length" type="text" placeholder="cm" name="length[1][]"/>
 <input id="length" type="text" placeholder="cm" name="length[1][]"/>
 <a href="#!" class="btn">add field</a>
</div>
<a href="#!" class="btn">add design</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try it.. :)

Comment: Mas atmahadli.. Can I ask one more question? How to generate the index in the name dynamically? I mean use: length[{{ordered number}}][] doesn't work either.. :)

Comment: are you using angular? or other? you can create separate question for this :p I'm still new to angular, mostly using jquery.

Comment: Oke, makasih mas.. Actually I hope there is a person who can help me solve several of my problem when play PHP script.. Especially in array stuff.. That a lot of confusion now.. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of code if it's helpful for you so its great for me.

```
$value = array('length','length');
$i = 1;
$loop = 2;
while($i <= $loop){
  echo "Design ".$i;
  foreach($value as $v){
     echo $v."<br/>";
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you four your great code... But I'm still not get it,